# Filter HTML elements Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, filter

Im trying to create a filter to filter different products but so far no success
ive tried different ways like using a long way by using IF for every filter didnt get it to work and code was way to big, tried for loop also wasnt able to do it

im trying to use "data" attribute in HTML to mark items seems to be a best way to do it?

any help is more then welcome

heres a code bellow

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.products')


buttons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        /* active button */
        buttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.classList.remove('active')
        })
        button.className = 'active'

        products.forEach(product => {
            showProduct = button.textContent
            
            if (product.getAttribute('data-filter') == showProduct.toLowerCase()){
                product.style.display = 'block'
            } else {
                product.style.display = 'none'
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-indigo-900 font-mono">
    <nav class="mt-4 mb-10 text-white">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-8">
                <li class=" transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
                    <a class="active btn filter-btn" href="#">All</a>
                </li>
                <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
                    <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Cake</a>
                </li>
                <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
                    <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Cookies</a>
                </li>
                <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
                    <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Donuts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
                    <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Pudding</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section class="container mx-auto flex flex-row justify-center items-center ">
            <div class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-4 grid-rows-4 gap-10 ">
                <!-- cakes -->
                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='cake' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/291528/pexels-photo-291528.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='cake' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1070850/pexels-photo-1070850.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- cookies -->
                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='cookies' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/890577/pexels-photo-890577.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='cookies' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020585/pexels-photo-1020585.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- donuts -->
                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='donuts' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2955820/pexels-photo-2955820.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='donuts'  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3656118/pexels-photo-3656118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- pudding -->
                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='pudding' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302468/pexels-photo-302468.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
                    <div class="w-full h-48">
                        <img data-filter='pudding' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3026801/pexels-photo-3026801.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products w-full h-full object-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-6">
                      <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="mt-2">
                        Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
                      </p>
                      <div class="mt-4 flex">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600" >View Source</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you are looking to hide everything except what button you press.

1. I would first place a helper class to hide elements I want to filter out of the dom using classList to toggle the class with `remove()` and `add()`
2. I would move the ***dataset.filter*** attribute to the parent element `.products` rather than use the image as a reference and try to travel up the DOM to target the parent element.
3. Remove and rename your image class to `products-img` so it is different than the products parent element.
4. Use a callback to add to your **eventListener** that checks the `targetBtn` value or `textContent` run it through an **forEach** loop and if statement to handle the **All** button, showing all elements.
5. *else* we run a **forEach** over products, first hiding all elements and then matching our ***dataset.filter*** value using a conditional that checks if it is equal to e.target.textContent button.

See example below:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.products')

function filterButtons(e) {
  let targetBtn = e.target.textContent.toLowerCase()
  targetBtn === 'all' ?
    products.forEach(p => {
      p.classList.contains('hide') ?
        p.classList.remove('hide') : null
    }) :
  products.forEach(p => {
    p.classList.add('hide')
    p.dataset.filter === targetBtn ?
      p.classList.remove('hide') : null
  })
}


buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', filterButtons)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-indigo-900 font-mono">
  <nav class="mt-4 mb-10 text-white">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <ul class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-8">
        <li class=" transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
          <a class="active btn filter-btn" href="#">All</a>
        </li>
        <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
          <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Cake</a>
        </li>
        <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
          <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Cookies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
          <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Donuts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="transition transform duaration-100 hover:scale-110">
          <a class="btn filter-btn" href="#">Pudding</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <section class="container mx-auto flex flex-row justify-center items-center ">
      <div class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-4 grid-rows-4 gap-10 parent">
        <!-- cakes -->
        <div data-filter='cake' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/291528/pexels-photo-291528.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-filter='cake' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1070850/pexels-photo-1070850.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- cookies -->
        <div data-filter='cookies' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/890577/pexels-photo-890577.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-filter='cookies' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020585/pexels-photo-1020585.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- donuts -->
        <div data-filter='donuts' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2955820/pexels-photo-2955820.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-filter='donuts' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3656118/pexels-photo-3656118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- pudding -->
        <div data-filter='pudding' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302468/pexels-photo-302468.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-filter='pudding' class="w-72 products max-w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white">
          <div class="w-full h-48">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3026801/pexels-photo-3026801.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="products-img w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </div>
          <div class="p-6">
            <h5 class="text-lg font-medium">Card title</h5>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Some simple text that describes what's going on in this very simple card.
            </p>
            <div class="mt-4 flex">
              <a href="https://www.google.com" class="inline-block rounded-sm font-medium border border-solid cursor-pointer text-center transition-colors duration-200 text-base py-3 px-6 text-white bg-green-400 border-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-600">View Source</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```